# Why is MyModel::data() not being called (subclassing QSqlQueryModel)

Tags: qt, view, model, qtableview, model-view

Hi I can't figure out why my `data()` function is never called when populating QTableView

I subclassed QSqlQueryModel. The header is like:

```
class TicketModel : public QSqlQueryModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TicketModel(QObject *parent = 0);

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role);
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const;

};
```

In the main window I set my model to the table

```
TicketModel *model = new TicketModel();
QSortFilterProxyModel *proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
proxyModel->setSourceModel(model);

QSqlQuery *query = _tf->search(1); 
model->setQuery(*query); 

_ui->dashTable->setModel(proxyModel);    // <<<<<<<<<<<<<< I setting model here too, didn't work
_ui->dashTable->setSortingEnabled(true);              
_ui->dashTable->horizontalHeader()->setVisible(true);  
_ui->dashTable->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
```

The `TicketModel::headerData(...)` is called but `TicketModel::data(...)` is never called when the table is created. Why? How can I get it to be called?

I hope I just overlooked something simple but I have been trying for a few hours to figure it out.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the signature wrong.  You need a const.

QVariant data( const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole ) const

Comment: I knew I had to be missing something super simple. Thank you so much!!